# How to force a 2d shape for both 1d and 2d arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm getting this error when running my code.

```
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead
```

I looked this up and I think I know why but not sure how to fix it.  I have a 2D array as a source but I need to take a specific column of the arrays for processing. When I get the columns out the 2D array turns into to a 1D array.

Here's my code:

```
    print(dataframe)
    location = orginalDataframe.columns.get_loc(item) #get the location of the current numberic item
    print(dataframe[:, location])
    dataframe[item] = scaler.inverse_transform(dataframe[:,location]) #reverse previous transformation
```

First print statement gives me this:

```
[[0.96570218]
 [0.96570218]
 [1.        ]
 [1.        ]
 [0.86415196]
 [0.86415196]
 [0.82511791]
 [0.82511791]]
```

2D, but after I do the `dataframe[:, location])` command it turns it into this:

```
[0.96570218 0.96570218 1.         1.         0.86415196 0.86415196
 0.82511791 0.82511791 0.91828023 0.91828023 0.76760661 0.76760661
 0.69375734 0.69375734 0.70177708 .. ]
```

In my current example, there is just one column here but for others, there is multiple columns.  Regardless of how many columns there are, how do I maintain the column as 2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you index the array on a column with:

```
location = orginalDataframe.columns.get_loc(item)
dataframe[:, location]
```

You could just add a new axis on that indexing to ensure your resulting array is two-dimensional through `reshape`:

```
dataframe[:, location].reshape(-1, 1)
```

Here's an example using a sample array, in the case of indexing on a column:

```
a[:,3].reshape(-1, 1).shape
# (15, 1)
```

The result is a 2D-array, and if we index on 2 columns:

```
a[:,[3,4]].reshape(-1,1).shape
# (30, 1)
```

The resulting array is also 2D

Comment: It it only has one axis yes, it adds one @Lostsoul

Comment: It just adds one new dimension. You can just `squeeze` it back to its original shape @Lostsoul

Comment: Thank you it worked, i did             comparison = dataArray == dataframe
            equal_arrays = comparison.all()
            print(equal_arrays). returns True! Thanks